# What was Grant looking for at the end of the season 3 finale?

Tags: plot-explanation, travelers

In the final scene of the Season 3 Finale of *Travelers*, just when he sends an email to the 'Director', Grant appears to look through the window, as if he is awaiting/expecting something to happen.

What was he looking for? Or is he just enjoying the scenery?

Comment: I haven't started season 3 yet, but I'm coming!!!!!!!!! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He's checking for a plane.

Grant's in the World Trade Center tower on September 11, 2001 (we get to see a scene in the same office play out a certain way at the very start of Season 1).

You'll notice he keeps checking the time and we see it's about 8:40am ish. The first plane struck the tower at 8:46am so we're lead to believe after his activity in the office that's about the time he chooses to look out the window.

Comment: Thanks. That contradicts The traveler's mission. Why wouldn't he alert them? Travelers mission is to save people. Why wouldn't he then?

Comment: @Saariko ugh... not sure how much to say without spoiling it for others... but prior to that scene after "project omega" (the mission is over) is declared, Grant gets to "travel" back to Grant again at a specific time and location (the one he remembers is where he and his wife first met) and the timeline's different. He presumably (and we see him do so a few things) changes that instances timeline and thus he's looking out the window in satisfaction that the plane isn't coming to hit the tower.